# How to make Æ Ø Å copyable from the PDF output

Tags: pdftex, pdf, copy-paste

When building a PDF file with LaTeX the character `å` gets uncopyable. It only results in

> `̊a`

when copied.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[norsk]{babel} 


\begin{document}
Try copying this åæø and the å gets strange..

\end{document}
```

This question is not the same as the one it's marked duplicate of. They do not address the problem with copying ÆØÅ. As you see in Sveinungs answer, he still has problem to copy the characters.

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`  and naturally inputenc: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` if your document is utf8 encoded.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm sure this has been asked before, but I'm unable to find the original question...

Comment: I didn't find anything @yo'

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Tried both, none of them worked. I'm on a mac.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: "None of them worked" is not a sensible problem description.

Comment: You told me to try two packages, none of them gave a solution to the problem.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I believe he asks about copyable text, not the specific characters I have trouble with. Also, if you look in the answer of Sveinung, he also is unable to copy ÆØÅ.

Comment: @miniHessel If I add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, everything works. However it depends on the editor you're using; it may be set up for a different encoding, perhaps `latin9` instead of `utf8`.

Comment: In addition to what @egreg says, could you detail your operating system, PDF viewer and TeX system version?

Comment: Tried with OS X viewer and Skim on OS X, same on both. Tried with different TeX version, doesn't change.

Comment: Evince and Adobe Reader tested on Linux using Ulrikes suggestion, copying text works just fine. All text is copied. Can you post the PDF somewhere we can download it?

Comment: Here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1255736/test.pdf

Comment: I can copy and paste without any problems from your test file: "Try copying this åæø and the å gets strange"

Comment: Then it's Mac who uses a strange encoding?

Comment: Update, if I open the PDF in Google Chrome, it's copyable.

Comment: Also works fine in FF.

Comment: It is not Mac using a strange encoding, the file is the same. It might be worth looks at what exactly you are copying the text into.

Comment: Into MS WORD in both cases.. But have tried Sublime etc.

Comment: Have you tried pasting into a terminal?

Comment: You know what, the \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} fixed it! The reason I didn't know it was because I copied into sublime(which doesn't work).. If I copy it to word, it works perfectly now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Just tested SublimeText on a Mac and it clearly have a problem. The standard text editor on the Mac has no problem with pasting the data.

Comment: I can't create an answer as the question is a duplicate.

Comment: It actually isn't a duplicate, because the problem is SublimeText.

Comment: Either (1) It's a dupe or (2) it's off-topic (bout SublimeText)!